# Can't get bootstrap vertical image alignment to work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm currently working on one website and I'm using bootstrap 3. What I'm trying to do is to align a few different sized images vertically. They seem to be aligned to the top but I want to center them.

Here is an image for you to understand better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpuq2.jpg

I tried things like this: [Center Image Vertically and Horizontally in Bootstrap Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702756/center-image-vertically-and-horizontally-in-bootstrap-grid)
this: https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-1211448a2eff
and this: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/utilities/vertical-align/

None of it worked though.

The best solution seems to be updating to bootstrap 4 but I'm afraid that I'd break my entire website...

Comment: If you are not want to update Bootstrap, Then why not custom css, You can use flex.

Comment: Plz use the classname "align-middle" insteadof "image-center"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As respect of my comment, I'm posted an answer.

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-container img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150X75">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150X100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150X45">
</div>
```